# Set CA field to true in basicConstraints for Cert in Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, pki

I am trying to set up a self-signed cert to use as a CA for creating client certs in Azure Key Vault. However, when I try to use the cert to generate a new cert, I get the following error:

> "The issuer certificate does not have an appropriate value for the
> Basic Constraints extension. (Parameter 'issuerCertificate')"

My understanding is that I need to set the CA field to true in the basicConstraints for the cert. However I see no way of doing this in the Portal or via CLI commands?

Edit: I was able to work around this by making a cert programmatically in C#, where I added the BasicConstraints extension, and then importing it. (But I am still interested in a way of doing it when generating a cert in Key Vault.)